# Connect to Azure Blob Storage using SFTP Private Key File

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, sftp, ssh-keys

When I tried to connect with the Azure Blob Storage with the SFTP using Console Application in C#
I am Getting an Error that THE CONNECTION IS CLOSED BY THE SERVER.
I have checked that the WINSCP I am able to connect.

Sample Code that I am Using.

```
using System;
using Renci.SshNet;
using WinSCP;

namespace SFTPTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
  
            // Replace these with your own values
            string host = "blobstoragetest.blob.core.windows.net";
            string username = "user1";
            string privateKeyFilePath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\Key";
            string privateKeyPassphrase = "Key";
            int port = 22;

            // Load the private key from file
            var privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile(privateKeyFilePath, privateKeyPassphrase);

            // Set up the connection info
            var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(host, port, username,
                new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, privateKey));

            // Connect to the SFTP server
            using (var sftp = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
            {
                sftp.Connect();

                // Do SFTP operations here

                sftp.Disconnect();
            } 


        }
    }
}
```

I have checked that the WINSCP I am able to connect. Also I am Unable to get the What is the Extension of the File I downloaded while Creating a SSH Key in Azure

Comment: Are you running your code and WinSCP on the same machine? Post WinSCP log. Post exact SSH.NET exception and its callstack and log.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same code which you shared and able to connect the Azure Blob storage using sftp without any errors.

The namespace to be used is `using Renci.SshNet;`

While creating user in sftp, you need to download the key and the key has to be used in the code.

[image]

Able to connect the Azure Blob storage using sftp without any errors.

[image]

Here the username to be used in the code is **storageaccount**.**username** of sftp.

[image]

Using WinScp also able to connect and uploaded files.

1. Connected to WinScp

[image]

2. Uploaded the sample files with Sftp.

[image]

In Azure portal.

[image]

For further information on this, refer to [Sftp-Blob-Storage.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/secure-file-transfer-protocol-support)